# How to prevent dialog to appear when I go to previous fragment after dialog has been dismissed?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

So right now, when I go to `Fragment B` from `Fragment A`, and show a dialog in the `onCreate()` of `Fragment B`, and then dismissed it (by clicking on the close button of the dialog) and go back to previous fragment(`Fragment A`) the dialog appears again for some reason(in `Fragment A`). If I repeat the action for example 5 times and go back each of those 5 times (to the previous fragment[`Fragment A`]) the dialog appears 5 times in a row in the previous fragment(`Fragment A`) . For some reason he is recording the dialogs that are being shown.

**So my dialog code is this:**

```
fun Fragment.showDialog(fragment: DialogFragment, tag: String) {
    val ft = fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
    val dialog = fragmentManager?.findFragmentByTag(tag) as? DialogFragment
    dialog?.let {
        ft?.remove(it)
    }
    dialog.
    ft?.addToBackStack(null)
    fragment.show(ft, tag)
}
```

**My call to the dialog in the fragment is this:**

```
showDialog(SuccessDialog.newInstance(), SuccessDialog.TAG)
```

**My success dialog fragment is this:**

```
class SuccessDialog : DialogFragment() {

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "SUCESS_DIALOG"
        fun newInstance() = SuccessDialog()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View =
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_success, container, false)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        dialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent)
        dialog?.window?.setDimAmount(0.8f)

        closeButton.setOnClickListener {
           dialog.cancel()
            dialog.dismiss()
        }

    }
}
```

This is my activity main back press body:

```
supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
```

Comment: can you add FragmentA and Fragment B, as well whoever opened fragmentA?

Comment: Fragment A and B are to long and I think they dont bring anything to the table because its only with the dialog showing problem. :/ I can put my main activity back press for you to take a look.

Comment: Hard to say, but one things that smells weird to me is adding a dialog fragment to the back stack. That's not something that's usually done. Maybe remove the add to stack and the pop back stack calls. Also, show the full code where you show the dialog.